# Kendo AutoComplete Not Displaying

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a custom editor that I use with autocomplete. The web service is getting called and returning the data. However, nothing is diaplying in the editor. I put a breakpoint in schema.parse() but it's never hit. What am I missing?

```
function myAutoCompleteEditor(container, options) {
    $('<input data-text-field="Name" data-value-field="Name" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoAutoComplete({
            autoBind: false,
            suggest: true,
            delay: 500,
            dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
                serverFiltering: true,
                transport: {
                    read: function (opt) {
                        $.getJSON("/myWebService/GetData");
                    },
                },
                schema: {
                    errors: function (e) {
                        return e;
                    },
                    parse: function (data) {
                        return data.Name;
                    }
                }
            })
        });
}
```

**UPDATE:**

The data, when shown via JSON.stringfy(data) is like this:

[{"Address":"123 1st St.","ID":"1","Name":"David"},{"Address":"234 2nd St.","ID":"2","Name":"Smith"}]

**UPDATE 2:**

The code looks like this now:

```
function myAutoCompleteEditor(container, options) {
    $('<input data-text-field="Name" data-value-field="Name" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoAutoComplete({
            dataValueField: "Name",
            autoBind: false,
            suggest: true,
            delay: 500,
            dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
                serverFiltering: true,
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: function (opt) {
                            return "/myWebServices/GetData/" + opt.filter.filters[0].value;
                        },
                        dataType: "json"
                    }                        
                },
                schema: {
                    errors: function (e) {
                        return e;
                    }
                },
                data: function (response) {
                    return $.parseJSON(response);
                }
            })
        });
}
```

**UPDATE 3:**

Finally got it working by removing the schema and data section. Accepting OnaBai's answer since he definitely pointed me to the right direction. The final code looks like this:

```
function myAutoCompleteEditor(container, options) {
    $('<input data-text-field="Name" data-value-field="Name" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoAutoComplete({
            dataValueField: "Name",
            autoBind: false,
            suggest: true,
            delay: 500,
            dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
                serverFiltering: true,
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: function (opt) {
                            return "/myWebServices/GetData/" + opt.filter.filters[0].value;
                        },
                        dataType: "json"
                    }                        
                }
            })
        });
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the implementation of [`read`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-transport.read) function. This function should invoke `opt.success` with data that you want to return. What you are doing is retrieving data from a URL but you are not returning such data.

But in your case it seem that you don't do anything special (no need for defining a function). So you can define it as an `Object` and just define [`transport.read.url`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-transport.read.url)

You can use:

```
dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
    serverFiltering: true,
    transport: {
        read: {
            url : "/myWebService/GetData"
        }
    },
    schema: {
        parse: function (data) {
            return data.Name;
        }
    }
})
```

**EDIT**: For using the data as the server returns it and do not have to parse, you can use:

```
function myAutoCompleteEditor(container, options) {
    $('<input data-text-field="Name" data-value-field="Name" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>').appendTo(container).kendoAutoComplete({
        autoBind      : false,
        suggest       : true,
        delay         : 500,
        dataValueField: "Name",
        dataSource    : new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url : "/myWebService/GetData"
                }
            }
        })
    });
}
```

The trick is defining `dataValueField` that defines which value of the returned array is the value of the `autocomplete`.

Comment: OnaBai, thanks for the reply. I followed your code and was able to get the breakpoint hit on parse(). However, the data shows "undefined" though it does have data in it ([[object, object][object,object]....]). How do I refer to it? Also, I hardcoded the url but in reality I need to url to be like "/myWebService/GetData/" + (whatever the user input is), how do I do that?

Comment: Please, can you show the format of the returned data? try inserting a `console.log(data)` in the parse function or `alert(JSON.stringify(data));` and update the Original Post. I will take a look into it.

Comment: OnaBai, thanks. I've updated my original post regarding the data.

Comment: OnaBai, adding dataValueField still didn't work for me. The breakpoint in schema.errors actually got hit but when I looked into the e object it contained exactly the same data as the web service returns and no errors. I've udpate the code to show you schema.errors()